# ajax returned form is not prevented using event.preventdefault()

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, forms

i have 2 files testjquery.php and abcd.php
on form submit calling ajax call and submitting it with ajax method. first times it prevents the forms defaultevent using event.preventdefault and loads  response data from the other page into the div .
But when again i try to submit it, the event.preventdefault doesnt work on the form.
Please help. Thanks in advance.

// testjquery.php

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <title>Untitled Document</title>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>


    <div id="abc">
      <form action="abcd.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="cartform">
        <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%" border="0">
          <tr>
            <th>QTY</th>
            <th>Item Description</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">Item Price</th>
            <th style="text-align:right">Sub-Total</th>
          </tr>
          <input type="hidden" name="cartrowid[1]" value="d68b70f3503216b22484eef9c786124a" />
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="cartrowqty[1]" value="1" maxlength="3" size="5"  /></td>
            <td> micromax_A12112
              <p> <strong>Size:</strong> L<br />
                <strong>Color:</strong> Red<br />
              </p></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">123.00</td>
            <td style="text-align:right">$123.00</td>
          </tr>
          <input type="hidden" name="cartrowid[2]" value="e376db925db6430cf3e82c3854b4f5e2" />
          <tr>
            <td><input type="text" name="cartrowqty[2]" value="1" maxlength="3" size="5"  /></td>
            <td> Indian_Saree
              <p> <strong>Size:</strong> L<br />
                <strong>Color:</strong> Red<br />
              </p></td>
            <td style="text-align:right">2,555.00</td>
            <td style="text-align:right">$2,555.00</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
        <p>
          <input type="submit" name="add_item_via_ajax_form" value="Update your Cart" class="add_item_via_ajax_form"  />
        </p>
      </form>
        <a href="http://w3schools.com/">Go to W3Schools.com</a>
    <p>The preventDefault() method will prevent the link above from following the URL.</p>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <script>
    $(function() 
    {


        // Example of adding a item to the cart via a link.
        $('.add_item_via_ajax_form').click(function(event)
        {
            alert(1);
            event.preventDefault();

            // Get the parent form.
            var parent_form = $(this).closest('form');

            // Get the url the ajax form data to be submitted to.
            var submit_url = parent_form.attr('action');

            // Get the form data.
            var $form_inputs = parent_form.find(':input');
            var form_data = {};
            $form_inputs.each(function() 
            {
                form_data[this.name] = $(this).val();
            });

            $.ajax(
            {
                url: submit_url,
                type: 'POST',
                data: form_data,
                success:function(data)
                {
                    //alert(data);
                        event.preventDefault();
                    ajax_update_mini_cart(data);
                }
            });
        });

        // A function to display updated ajax cart data from the mini cart menu.
        function ajax_update_mini_cart(data)
        {   


            $('#abc').html(data);

            $('#mini_cart_status').show();

            // Set the new height of the menu for animation purposes.
            var min_cart_height = $('#mini_cart ul:first').height();
            $('#mini_cart').attr('data-menu-height', min_cart_height);
            $('#mini_cart').attr('class', 'js_nav_dropmenu');

            // Scroll to the top of the page.
            $('body').animate({'scrollTop':0}, 250, function()
            {
                // Notify the user that the cart has been updated by showing the mini cart.
                $('#mini_cart ul:first').stop().animate({'height':min_cart_height}, 400).delay(3000).animate({'height':'0'}, 400, function()
                {
                    $('#mini_cart_status').hide();
                });
            });
        }
    });
    </script>
    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $("a").click(function(event){
        event.preventDefault();
      });
    });
    </script>


//abcd.php

<form action="abcd.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" name="cartform">
    <table cellpadding="6" cellspacing="1" style="width:100%" border="0">
      <tr>
        <th>QTY</th>
        <th>Item Description</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">Item Price</th>
        <th style="text-align:right">Sub-Total</th>
      </tr>
      <input type="hidden" name="cartrowid[1]" value="d68b70f3503216b22484eef9c786124a" />
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cartrowqty[1]" value="1" maxlength="3" size="5"  /></td>
        <td> micromax_A12112
          <p> <strong>Size:</strong> L<br />
            <strong>Color:</strong> Red<br />
          </p></td>
        <td style="text-align:right">123.00</td>
        <td style="text-align:right">$123.00</td>
      </tr>
      <input type="hidden" name="cartrowid[2]" value="e376db925db6430cf3e82c3854b4f5e2" />
      <tr>
        <td><input type="text" name="cartrowqty[2]" value="1" maxlength="3" size="5"  /></td>
        <td> Indian_Saree
          <p> <strong>Size:</strong> L<br />
            <strong>Color:</strong> Red<br />
          </p></td>
        <td style="text-align:right">2,555.00</td>
        <td style="text-align:right">$2,555.00</td>
      </tr>

    </table>
    <p>
      <input type="submit" name="add_item_via_ajax_form" value="Update your Cart" class="add_item_via_ajax_form"  />
    </p>
  </form>
  <a href="http://w3schools.com/">Go to W3Schools.com</a>
<p>The preventDefault() method will prevent the link above from following the URL.</p>
```

Comment: Are you clicking on ajax loaded content?

Comment: yes i m clicking ajax loaded content again

Comment: you could have better to prevent default submiting of the FORM, what should happen if user press `return` inside FORM? Should it submit FORM?

Comment: see once submitted, ajax data returns form again, user need to submit it again. for that preventdefault doesnt work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should delegate event, e.g:

```
$('#abc').on('click', '.add_item_via_ajax_form', function(event){
     //...
});
```

See @my question's comment regarding FORM submit instead

Comment: Sorry, in my example, forgot to pass `event`, maybe you see issue on firefox then

Comment: thankyou. problem solved with your solution too. Simple and compact.

Comment: <script>
 $(document).ready(function(e) {
   //$('#sub_nav').on('click', '.remove_item', function(event) 
        $(".quantity_box_button_up").click(function(e) {
            
         var abc=parseInt(($(this).prev("input").val()));
   
   $(this).prev("input").val(abc+1);
  });
   $(".quantity_box_button_down").click(function(e) {
            
         var bbc=parseInt(($(this).next("input").val()));
   alert(bbc);
   if(bbc==1)
   {
    
   }
   else
   {
    $(this).next("input").val(bbc-1);
   }
   
  });
  
  
    });
</script>

Comment: i have this jquery to increment and decrement value in text box it work fine but doesnt work on ajax data. I tried to do it the way you suggested above but not working at all on normal data too

Comment: <div><input type="button" class="quantity_box_button_down" value="-" ><input type="text" name="cartrowqty[1]" value="7" maxlength="3" size="5"  /><input type="button" class="quantity_box_button_up" value="+" ></div>

Comment: @vithal04 Please post a new question with your specific problem, someone should be able to help you

Answer (score 2):

The line

```
$('#abc').html(data);
```

replaces all content of the div id="abc" with the new html code from the ajax request.

This new content does not have any event handler attached and the form is submitted the 'normal' way. To fix it, you must add a new

```
$('.add_item_via_ajax_form').click(function(event) {}
```

in your

```
function ajax_update_mini_cart(data) {}
```

after

```
$('#abc').html(data);
```

This will add the handler and the form will be submitted via ajax every time.